# Layout layout.reingold.tilford issue ploting a tree in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, tree, igraph

I´m trying to plot a Tree using igraph and started from very simple examples available on the web, one of them is

```
library(igraph)
el <- matrix( c("root", "y", "root", "x", "x", "a", "x", "b"), nc=2, byrow=TRUE)
g13 <- graph.edgelist(el)
co <- layout.reingold.tilford(g13, flip.y=TRUE)
plot(g13, layout=co)
```

The issue is I get all vertices on the same line, the root at left and the rest to right of it, as shown:

[image]

I tried other variations like

```
plot(g13, layout=layout.reingold.tilford)
```

and the results were the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems necessary to specify the root node:

```
co <- layout.reingold.tilford(g13, params=list(root=1))
plot(g13, layout=co)
```

[image]